# Why my program start on linux startup but get the runlevel is 0?

Tags: c++, linux, shell

i use c++ code run command "runlevel" on linux startup in multi-user mode (both rc.local and systemd), but all are get the runlevel is 0, why?

0 – halt
1 – single user mode
2 – Multi-user, without NFS

Comment: Unclear question. Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot (it should be longer and  well formatted). Show some [MCVE] please explaining how do you get the `runlevel`. Notice that `system` gives the exit code, not the output, of some command. Maybe you want to use `popen`

Comment: `system("runlevel")` is very unlikely to not be 0, if that's what you're doing.

Comment: i use `popen()` to get the `runlevel` output, not use `system` to get the return code.

Comment: The answer is in runlevel man page!